# Codeigniter joined tables getting wrong output

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I'm having an function which gets data from my database, and joins different tables. This is the method:

```
public function getCallcenterCall() {
    $this->db->select('bedrijf.*, status.status_naam, quickscan.datum_verzonden');
    $this->db->join('quickscan', 'bedrijf.id = quickscan.bedrijf_id');
    $this->db->join('status', 'bedrijf.status = status.status_id');
    $this->db->where('status', '0');

    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijf');

    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query-> result_array() : FALSE;
}
```

In the table status I got 3 rows: `'id'`, `'status_id'`, `'status_naam'`. In my view, I output the `status_naam`, but here it gets wrong.

Instead of giving me the `'status_naam'` that belongs to `'status_id=0'`; it gives me the `'status_naam'` where `'status_id=1'`.

The same thing happens if I try to get the `'status_naam'` for `'status_id=1'` then it gives me the `'status_naam'` from `'status_id=2'`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your database setup to use foreign key constraints?

simple example :

Tables

```
create table `groups`(
`id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`name` varchar(30) not null,
`colour` varchar(7) not null,
`created_at` datetime not null,
`updated_at` datetime not null
 )engine=innodb;


create table `users`(
`id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`group_id` int(10) unsigned not null,
`permissions` varchar(255) not null default '{[u, r, d]}',
`created_at` datetime not null,
`updated_at` datetime not null,
index(group_id),
foreign key(group_id) references groups(id)
)engine=innodb;
```

Raw SQL

```
select g.name, u.permissions from users as u
left join groups as g
on g.id = u.group_id
where id=1
```

As you can see you set an index of `group_id` on the users table,
then set it as our foreign key and tell it to reference the `groups` id.

innodb engine is required & the rows must match identically.

...hope that makes sense

Comment: You were right, my status was endum and my status_id was int. This solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to use the third parameter of `join`, e.g.

```
$this->db->join('quickscan', 'bedrijf.id = quickscan.bedrijf_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('status', 'bedrijf.status = status.status_id', 'inner');
```

If that still fails, you might have to go with a custom query instead:

```
$s  = 'SELECT ';
$s .=    'bedrijf.*, status.status_naam, quickscan.datum_verzonden ';
$s .= 'FROM bedrijf ';
$s .= 'INNER JOIN quickscan ON bedrijf.id = quickscan.bedrijf_id ';
$s .= 'INNER JOIN status ON bedrijf.status = status.status_id ';
$s .= 'WHERE (status = ?)';

$query = $this->db->query($s, array('0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the from method?

```
$this->db->select...
$this->db->from('bedrijf')
...
$query = $this->db->get()
...
```