# Joining queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two functions and i want to make it like one.

function 1

```
public function getAlliancesList($pageIndex, $pageSize)
{
    return $this->provider->fetchResultSet("SELECT  a.id, a.name, a.player_count, a.rating    FROM p_alliances a    ORDER BY a.rating DESC, a.player_count DESC, a.id ASC    LIMIT %s,%s", array($pageIndex * $pageSize, $pageSize));
}
```

function 2

```
public function getAllianceAverage($allianceId)
{
    $row = $this->provider->fetchRow("SELECT AVG(p.total_people_count) as average FROM p_players p WHERE p.alliance_id = '%s'", array($allianceId));
    return intval($row['average']);
}
```

Basically I want to join function 2 into function 1 so I don't need 2 query's and I can then call that one function on the template file like `$this->datalist->row['average']` if this is even possible.

I've tried a lot of ways to get the two queries to work together but to no avail so any help would be great.

EDIT:

What i want is to include the alliance id in `getAllianceList` function

this is how we tried till now:

```
public function getAlliancesList($pageIndex, $pageSize)
        {
            return $this->provider->fetchResultSet("SELECT *
FROM `p_alliances`
JOIN `p_players` 
ON `p_players`.`id` = `p_alliances`.`id`  LIMIT %s,%s", array($pageIndex * $pageSize, $pageSize));
        }
```

Comment: please provide more details - what's the table's structure, how are they linked? can you show us what you tried? (and what's $this->provider?); and somehow, these queries seem to do completely separate things (the one returns one row, the other several) - what's your goal in that, why do you want to combine them?

Comment: [I have answered a similar question here, hopefully it might help you understand](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8548280/337055) If not let me know and Ill try help out.

Comment: doesnt make sense to me yet.not that experienced thats why i need help:)

Comment: I would need to see your database structure before I could alter tables or write a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    a.player_count,
    a.rating,
    AVG(p.total_people_count) AS `average`
FROM p_alliances a
    INNER JOIN p_players p ON (p.alliance_id = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.rating DESC, a.player_count DESC, a.id ASC
LIMIT %s,%s
```

If there could be 0 players you might want to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, but it may impact performance in mysql.

Comment: Works, thanks for normal, short and clear answer. Thats how I like it, thanks again.